# Core Data relationship breaks on updating DB - Restkit

Tags: ios, core-data, mapping, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have two entities 'Parent' and 'Child'. Parent Entity has one-many relationship with Child Entity and child has one-one relationship with parent and "Parent" Entity has an unique id (primary key attribute) which i am mapping each time.

When i call an API, the response is coming like this

```
{
    "parent": {
        "ss": "1",
        "uid": 200,
        "me": "Successfully Retrieved",
        "pn": 2,
        "cl": [
            {
                "cid": 1500,
                "cn": "XYZ"
            },
            {
                "cid": 1501,
                "cn": "ABC"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The above response is successfully mapped to DB. i can access by [parent.childs allObjects] which returns two objects.

I have an load more functionality which is calling same api and page number incremented by 1 and i get the response(3 objects)  similar to above one. But when i try to fetch data from DB i get only 3 objects that came on latest response. The relationship for the two object that i mapped earlier becomes empty. so i am not able to access all objects. How can i access all data from DB by relationship.

This is how i am mapping

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [[RestKit sharedDataManager] objectManager];
        RKEntityMapping *parentMapping = [[MFResponseMapper sharedInstance]parentMapper]; //Primary key is mapping here
        RKEntityMapping *childMapping = [[MFResponseMapper sharedInstance]childMapper]; //Child name and Id is mapping here.

        [parentMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"cl"
                                                                                    toKeyPath:@"childs"
                                                                                  withMapping:childMapping]];


        RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:parentMapping
                                                                                       pathPattern:nil
                                                                                           keyPath:@"parent"
                                                                                       statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

        [manager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

Note: i have delete rule for Parent-Child (one-many) relationship in model.

Thanks

Comment: Are you saving the database after you add these entities? There is a difference between modifying a context and saving to the underlying store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the relationship mapping, set the `assignmentPolicy` to `RKUnionAssignmentPolicy`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
parentMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"uid"];
```

and

```
childMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"cid"];
```

The reason why you have to do this is because otherwise it would just create another parent with the 3 children and that's what you are seeing. So basically after you call the API again you will have 2 parents from the 2 API calls with the corresponding children (two and three).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. as i mentioned, i have using primary key(identification atribute) for my parent and child. i am not getting any duplicate records of my parent. but child entity is entirely updated with new one. so i can able to access only the new records.